# MS Teams, remove user for group why, please

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I don't now who and why delete user from group, in log i see information about User-Agent.
Azure Add without local AD,

SkypeSpaces/1.0a$*+

that all, where i can found more information

type:

Remove member from group

user:

"SkypeSpaces/1.0a$*+" and Display name "MS Teams Services"

I check log, i add again but nex day are this same, user remove from group

Comment: As mentioned in your query user agent belongs MS Teams Services, have you made any configuration changes to the teams ? seems like some automated task within teams is triggering this removal, user part of the teams group/channel does it have any configuration based on user attributes which is triggering this deletion. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/371768/an-unknown-user-created-a-year-ago-was-automatical.html                            https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-groups/understand-how-are-users-getting-added-to-a-group/m-p/3498695

Comment: There have been no changes to the teams and the issue is only affecting one user,
other users are in this group and it's ok, this user also belongs to other groups and it's ok

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to check the User deleted information from Group**

I have created one Group and deleted user from Groups by using following Steps

**Azure Portal > Groups >New Group**

[image]

Deleted members from the same Group.

Open the Same group **Azure Portal-Azure Active Directory>Groups (Manage)>Select the Group>Members>select the user>Remove**

[image]

Once remove the user group

**Azure Portal-Azure Active Directory>Groups (Manage)>Select the Group>Activity>Audit Logs**

[image]

To check the detailed Log information, open the Log

[image]

Comment: Activity type
Remove member from group
Correlation ID
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Category
GroupManagement
State
success
Condition cause
User agent
Initiated by (actor)
Type
App
Name displayed
Microsoft Team Services
Application ID
Service principal ID
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Service principal name
Additional details
User-Agent
SkypeSpaces/1.0a$*+

Comment: i change user name, and all works